# How do I format a date like "Sat, 1/26" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the format dialog, the closest option is "Wednesday, March 14, 2019", which is too verbose for me.

If I type that literal string into a cell, it doesn't become a date. Any fiddling with the formula "[$-x-sysdate]dddd, mm, dd, yy" appears to have no effect (e.g. changing dddd to dd, yy to yyyy)

Also, what would the formula be for "Sat, 1/26/19"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Also, what would the format be for "Sat, 1/26/19"?

Use:

```
ddd, m/dd/yy
```

Instructions:

> 1. In an Excel sheet, select the cells you want to format.
> 2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to open the Format Cells dialog.
> 3. On the Number tab, select Custom from the Category list and type the date format you want in the Type box.

Source [How to change Excel date format and create custom formatting](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/#custom-date-format)

Use the date format `ddd, m/dd/yy`

See the above link for a table showing all valid format specifiers.